# Cayley-Bacharach property and independent conditions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Z$ be a zero dimensional subscheme of $19$ distinct points in $ \mathbb P^3$ ( over $ \mathbb C$) such that it does not satisfy Cayley-Bacharach property for $\mathcal O(4)$.

This means that there exists a quartic $Q$ in $ \mathbb P^3$ and a subscheme $Z'$ of $Z$ of $18$ distinct points such that $Q$ passes through $Z'$ but not through $Z$.

Question : In this situation, can we conclude that $Z'$ does not impose independent conditions on $ \mathcal O(4)$?

I'm unable to see why this should be the case. Can we impose any condition on $Z$ or $Z'$ so that this happens?

In this context, does there exist a general relation between satisfying Cayley-Bacharach property and imposing independent conditions?

Any input from anyone is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A set of points $\{p_i\}$ imposes independent conditions if the conditions $F(p_i)=0$ are linearly independent on the space of polynomials.

If this property is satisfied, then the set of points is not Cayley-Bacharach with respect to those polynomials, because the last point imposes one more condition. That is, there were some polynomials that vanished at the first $n-1$ points but not at the last point.

In the case you gave, we can’t conclude anything about either the 19 points or the 18 points. I mean, just pick a quartic and pick 18 points on it (they can impose dependent conditions or not, as you want) and a 19th not on it.

You can think of Cayley-Bacharach as meaning “any $n-1$ of the $n$ points *impose the same conditions as* the full set of $n$ points.”

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can we atleast think for the possibility that instead of $Z'$, there exists atleast one colength $1$ subscheme of $Z$ which doesn't impose independent conditions on quartics? (For simplicity let's assume that $Z$ is on a smooth hypersurface of high degree in $\mathbb P^3$ and $Z$ can impose atmost $18$ conditions on quartics). Finally, I have one more question, is it true that : $h^0(I_Z(m)) = h^0( \mathcal O_X(m)) - \text{ no of independent conditions} \geq h^0( \mathcal O_X(m))- |Z|$.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the set $Z$ must fail to impose independent conditions (since the $n$-th point does not impose an additional condition). But, $Z’$ may or may not impose independent conditions. I think an example is: $14$ general points on a twisted cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are Cayley-Bacharach with respect to quartics (in fact a quartic containing $13$ of the points must contain the whole twisted cubic, by Bézout). But, I think those $13$ points impose independent conditions themselves.